# Why is my HTML file unable to use the JavaScript file that I have linked?

Tags: javascript, html, src

**JavaScript file is not used in the HTML file despite linking it**

I am unable to use the JavaScript file and validate my HTML form. I am wondering if the issue is the linking of the `src` directory is wrong or could it be that I am missing something in my JavaScript code.

[image: File Directory Image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registration Page</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="js/validation.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="validate" method="post" name="register">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="name" required/><br/> Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" required/><br/> Address Line 1: <input type="text" name="address1" required/><br/> Address Line 2: <input type="text" name="address2" /><br/>    Postal Code: <input type="number" name="postal" required/><br/> Mobile Number: <input type="number" name="mobile" required/><br/> Password: <input type="password" name="password" required/><br/> Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="cfpassword"
      required/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
function validateForm() {

  //Use a regular expression to check for the pattern of the password
  var regexPass = "^[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{1}$";
  var regexMobile = "^[0-9]{8}$";
  var regexPost = "^[0-9]{6}$";
  //Retrieve the VALUE from the "password" field found in the "register" form
  var password1 = document.forms["register"]["password"].value;
  var password2 = document.forms["register"]["cfpassword"].value;
  var postalcode = document.forms["register"]["postal"].value;

  if (matchPost === null) {
    alert("The postal code given in the correct format. Please ensure 
      that is contains exactly 6 digits.
      ");

      // Return false to tell the form NOT to proceed to the servlet
      return false;
    }
    if (matchMobile === null) {
      alert("The mobile number given in the correct format. Please ensure 
        that is contains exactly 8 digits.
        ");

        // Return false to tell the form NOT to proceed to the servlet
        return false;
      }

      // If password not entered 
      if (password1 == '')
        alert("Please enter Password");

      // If confirm password not entered 
      else if (password2 == '')
        alert("Please enter confirm password");

      // If Not same return False.     
      else if (password1 != password2) {
        alert("\nPassword did not match: Please try again...")
        return false;
      }

      // If same return True. 
      else {
        return true
      }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the `<script>` tag bellow the `<form>` tag? Also, if possible, show us what is inside validation.js

Comment: Why is this question tagged Java in spite of apparently having no Java content, whatsoever?

Comment: If you want to know if the validation.js file has been found, you can press F12 in Chrome browser to open the developper tools, then go to the Network tab. There, you can look for the validation.js file and verify it's status. If 200, it means that your file has been found.

Comment: You do know that the `action` of a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) is an URI (and not a function call), don't you?

Comment: Have you tried to use the browsers' included tools (F12) to check why it isn't working?

Comment: There is nothing in your JavaScript that associates `validateForm` to your HTML, nor anything in your HTML which associates the `validateForm` function to an event. Either add `onclick="validateForm()"` to your submit button's HTML, or preferably, add `document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', validateForm)` to the end of your JavaScript file (once you've fixed the syntax errors, and placed the `script` tag just before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JS folder is in the same directory as your html file this code should work. Write a simple `alert('ahoy')` function in your JS file and reload your html to verify if your JS file is loaded or not.